# Can't create Scripting.Dictionary or MSXML.DOMDocument60 in VBA since Windows Update KB4586781

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, windows-update

Some VBA code no longer works for me, when creating COM objects from standard libraries such as Microsoft Scripting Runtime or Microsoft Xml, v6.0.  I get an error on the line of instantiation, the error is code
80004021(-2147467231) and error description is `Automation error The operation attempted is not supported.`   But I can create C# code with interop references to these libraries perfectly fine.  I had an [Windows 10 update KB4586781](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4586781/windows-10-update-kb4586781) two days ago.

The code fails in both Excel VBA and Word VBA.  Anyone else with similar issues?

```
Sub TestCreate_Scripting_Dictionary()
    
    '* THIS CODE FAILS !!!!
    
    Dim lateBound As Object
    Set lateBound = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<=== FAILS 80004021
    ' ... Automation error The operation attempted is not supported.
    
    '* Tools->References->Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary  '<=== FAILS 80004021
    ' ... Automation error The operation attempted is not supported.


End Sub


Sub TestCreate_MSXML2_DOMDocument60()
    '* THIS CODE FAILS !!!!

    '* Tools->References->Microsoft Xml, v6.0
    Dim xml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60  '<=== FAILS 80004021
    ' ... Automation error The operation attempted is not supported.
    

End Sub
```

UPDATE: I was meaning to reinstall but it went away without any intervention.  Odd.

Comment: a s shot in the dark: did you try `Dim dict As Dictionary` and then `Set dict = New Dictionary` in the "'* Tools->References->Microsoft Scripting Runtime" section?

Comment: @user3598756 : you mean remove the "Scripting" prefix?  Just tried that, no difference.

Comment: yes I meant that, though had sort of a feeling the "Scripting" part would have been simply inferred from the interpreter...

Comment: @user3598756 : yeah I think Microsoft would back-test .NET Interop on Scripting.Dictionary, in fact in the C# IDE I can see some extension methods on the Scripting.Dictionary indicating ongoing development for use within C#.  I wonder if they back-test VBA with the same level of coverage.  They should!

Comment: the should... but they have a big problem with VBA: it's too useful and free to live! But there are also too many code and coders out there, that they can't simply dismiss. While loosing pieces along the way could be a winning (!) strategy in the mid-long term

Comment: I have just installed the update (restarted my system) after reading your post. Your code doesn't fail for me. Have you tried uninstalling the update? Also consider reinstalling it again.